# Virtual Audio Cable .bat file output/input device language error

Tags: batch-file, audio, virtual, codepages

I've been trying to set up a .bat file for launching my Virtual Audio Cable setup for easy use. It turned out to be more troublesome than first expected.

The special characters "ÆØÅ" that is found on my device names are messing up with the VAC application.

My .bat file looks as such:

```
chcp 1252
start /min "audiorepeater" "D:\Programmer\Virtual Audio Cable\audiorepeater.exe" /Input: "Mikrofon på headset (8-Logitec" /Output: "Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)" /BufferMs: 50 /Buffers: 8 /Autostart
start /min "audiorepeater" "D:\Programmer\Virtual Audio Cable\audiorepeater.exe" /Input: "Stereomix (2- Realtek High Defi" /Output: "Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)" /BufferMs: 50 /Buffers: 8 /Autostart
start /min "audiorepeater" "D:\Programmer\Virtual Audio Cable\audiorepeater.exe" /Input: "Stereomix (2- Realtek High Defi" /Output: "Øresnegl på headset (8-Logitec" /BufferMs: 50 /Buffers: 8 /Autostart
```

The Stereomix -> Line 1 works fine. The others bug out, even though I finally after hours of research managed to get it to treat "ÆØÅ" correctly (Is shown in the error message).

The error message now reads: "No output device "Øresnegl på headset (8-Logitec"" even though that's the exact name of the output device in the list.

It's saved as "All files" and ANSI. Also tried messing with it in notepad++. No luck.

Im at a loss on how to make VAC recognize the name correctly, it seems to be a codepage incompatibility.

Thanks,
lindenkron

Answer (score 1):

Go to your recording devices and change the name. Make it something else. It doesn't end with (8-Logitec) its much longer *u you just can't see it*.

Simply rename the device and then edit your .bat and save it out as .bat